Why does my module inherit a duplicate inactive views?
On my development server when I load my two plugins that modify website_sale.products_add_to_cart everything works fine and the views inherit the right one.

But when I look at the same view on my production site, I get a 'Multiple tree exists for this view' message and it appears as though the view that I'm trying to get to work attaches itself to a duplicate inactive view.


Anyone have any ideas why I might have multiple products_item and what I can do to make mine take ahold of the right one?
I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling my plugins and making the inactive view active.
